# Prove that left-shift invariant sigma-algebra is contained in the tail sigma-algebra wrt projections

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

Consider $(E, \mathcal E)$ – measurable space, the space $\Omega = E^\mathbb N$ equipped with product σ-sigma algebra $\mathcal F = \otimes_{n} \mathcal E$. Next define projections $\pi_n(\omega) = \omega_n$, their respective σ-algebras $\mathcal F_n = \sigma (\pi _n)$, and their generated tail σ-algebra by

$$\mathcal T _{\infty} = \cap _{n\in \mathbb N}\sigma (\cup_{m \geq n} \mathcal F _m)$$

Define the left-shift operator $\tau : \Omega \rightarrow \Omega$ by $(\pi_n \circ \tau) (\omega)= \omega_{n+1}$ and left-shift invariant σ-algebra

$$\mathcal I = \{A\in \mathcal F : \tau ^{-1}(A) = A\}$$

We want to show that $\mathcal I \subset \mathcal T _\infty$.

**My attempt:** I tried to prove it by induction: we need to show that for a fixed $A\in \mathcal I$ it also has to be in $\sigma (\cup_{m \geq n} \mathcal F _m)$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. I showed the inductive step $n \rightarrow n+1$ by proving the statement for the sets that generate $\sigma (\cup_{m \geq n} \mathcal F _m)$ of the form $\pi ^{-1}_k(B)$ for $k \geq n$ and $B \in \mathcal E$ (since $\tau^{-1}\circ \pi _n^{-1} = \pi _{n+1} ^{-1}$). However, I struggle to show the inductive basis $A \in \sigma (\cup_{m \geq 1} \mathcal F _m)$. So I am not sure if my approach is viable.

Help appreciated.

Comment: You want $\mathcal{F}_m$ instead of $\mathcal{F}_n$ in all your formulae.

Comment: correct, fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$\mathcal{F}=\bigotimes_n\mathcal{E}=\sigma(\pi_1,\pi_2,\pi_3,\dots)=\sigma\left(\bigcup_n\sigma(\pi_n)\right)=\sigma\left(\bigcup_n\mathcal{F}_n\right)$$
So $A\in\mathcal{F}\iff A\in\sigma\left(\bigcup_{m\geq 1}\mathcal{F}_m\right)$.

Comment: Okay I realized this like seconds ago, I was confused and thought that projections generate tail algebra, not the whole algebra. Thanks!